# Need help downloading and reading a zipped CSV file in memory with Clojure

Tags: csv, clojure

I have an external site from which I want to download a zipped CSV file. Currently, I'm downloading it unzipped, saving it to disk, then unzipping it, saving the unzipped file to disk, then reading the unzipped file with the CSV reader. Lots of useless steps in the process can be trimmed out, and I went on my way to do so.

[This amazing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32745253/7269570) helped me to get myself going. I tried to use the first option linked there (`GZIPInputStream`), but I get a "Not GZIP format" error, so I suppose I have to go to the second option.

This is my current code, and it does what I want it to do:

```clj
(defn download-zipped-stream!
  (:body (clj-http.client/get "www.example.com" {:as :stream})))

(with-open
  [stream (ZipInputStream. download-zipped-stream!)]
  (.getNextEntry stream)
  (doall (clojure.data.csv/read-csv (clojure.java.io/reader stream) :separator \;)))
```

I literally got to this by trial and error. There are mainly three things I'd like to change / understand about this code.

1. Ideally, I would want to break my code in two parts: one to download and unzip the content, returning a stream - the reason being that I want to decide later whether I want to read it as a csv directly, or write to disk (I don't want to lose this option, because, during development, it is much easier to read a pre-downloaded csv file than downloading the big content every single time). Turns out that, if I try to access the stream outside of the `with-open` call, I get a "stream closed" error (which, from what I understand, makes total sense).
2. On the above code, I have to call this `.getNextEntry`, or I get an empty list. As someone who is striving to write functional code, this bothers me, because, from what I can understand, I'm dealing with states here - my stream object looks mutable, which is something I really don't want. Isn't there a way to work around this step and straight-up not have it there?
3. I tried to call the `read-csv` method directly on the `stream` object, but the `read-csv` doesn't really know how to handle ZipInputStreams, apparently. Seeing this, I simply and hopefully throwed an `io/reader` call in between, and it worked. I don't know if this is the best approach, though. Is it correct?

I'm quite new to Clojure, and I'm completely clueless about Java in general, so, as you can see, my knowledge about those stream objects is pretty limited. I tried to read something about it in Java, but I quitted because I was not sure about how much of it could be useful for someone learning Clojure, so any pointers are also appreciated.

Comment: You can't do nothing for 2) except hiding that or looking for a library, that does the hiding for you - this is how the java class is implemented. If you
want to "hide" it a bit better, you can do something like `(-> stream (doto (.getNextEntry)) (clojure.java.io/reader) (clojure.data.csv/read-csv) (doall)))` which makes it look a bit more "pipeliney" than just the imperative call in between some lines. Yet I am not sure, what you question here is - this looks alot like a request for a code review?

Comment: Well, the 2. and 3. are review-ish, I agree (although I'm not so much trying to figure out whether this code is good, but rather if the concepts are correct, or if there are better alternatives), but I still don't know how to get the point 1 done - that is, return a stream and decide later what to do with it (perhaps as in a lazy stream, if that makes any sense)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are on the right approach.  Suggestions to consider:

1. Consider using `wget` to manually download the `*.csv.gz` file to your local disk.  Then, just open that local file instead of using `clj-http.client/get`.
2. I haven't played much with [ZipInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/zip/ZipInputStream.html), but if using `.getNextEntry()` seems to be required, just go with it.
3. The examples for [read-csv](https://github.com/clojure/data.csv) show using a Reader to give access to the input file, so this is the expected behavior.
4. [This template project](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template) shows how I like to organize a Clojure project & source code.  Be sure to peruse the list of documentation provided.
5. Don't forget to [utilize cljdoc.org](https://cljdoc.org/) for looking up Clojure library API docs. For example, see [the API docs for data.csv](https://cljdoc.org/d/org.clojure/data.csv/1.0.0/doc/readme).

---

### Update

You may also want to review [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41959409/decompress-zlib-stream-in-clojure).

Comment: OP want's to get rid of intermediate artifacts and steps, so suggesting to throw in a random shell tool seems like bad advice.

Comment: Given the OP comment "read a pre-downloaded csv file", I think `wget` or similar is the best approach to achieve a local cache of the file for dev work.

Comment: I get the idea, but I was looking for something integrated to the code, not exactly some utility (the whole point is to avoid going over things manually during development). FOr that purpose, I ended building two separate functions, one that downloads and saves to disk unzipped, and other that downloads, unzips and returns a sequence. Not sure if building a "lazy stream" is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Use https://github.com/techascent/tech.ml.dataset optionally with https://scicloj.github.io/tablecloth/index.html (a dplyr like api for TMD)

Also has advantage of being extremely fast and able to handle datasets that can't fit in memory, talks SQL, Arrow, et. al.  Join conversation about it here:
https://clojurians.zulipchat.com/#narrow/stream/151924-data-science/topic/tech.2Eml.2Edataset